# compatibility between sage and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, sage

Here are two lines of code for the purpose of generating a random permutation of size 4:

```
from numpy import random
t = random.permutation(4)
```

This can be executed in Python, but not sage, which gives the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-033ef4665637> in <module>()
      1 from numpy import random
----> 2 t = random.permutation(Integer(4))

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.permutation (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:34842)()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.shuffle (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:33796)()

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Why?

A bit more details: I executed the code in Python 3, and the `mtrand` is also in the Python 3 directory, which should rule out the possibility that sage is calling Python 2 version of the numpy.

Comment: Nonetheless, Sage as currently used only has Python 2 (though that will likely be changing in the near future, see https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/15530).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work in Sage is that Sage preparses its input, turning "4" from a Python `int` to a Sage `Integer`. In Sage, this will work:

```
from numpy import random
t = random.permutation(int(4))
```

Or you can turn the preparser off:

```
preparser(False)
t = random.permutation(4)
```

Answer (score 3):

To escape Sage's preparser, you can also append the letter `r` (for "raw") to numerical input.

```
from numpy import random
t = random.permutation(4r)
```

The advantage of `4r` over `int(4)` is that `4r` bypasses the
preparser, while `int(4)` is preparsed as `int(Integer(4))` so that
the Python integer is transformed into a Sage integer and then
transformed back into a Python integer.

In the same way, `1.5r` will give you a pure Python float rather than
a Sage "real number".